# How to update last row in table in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sql-update

I want to update last row data of a user in db table in laravel application.
Im trying to use orderBy id desc limit 1 but it couldn't work.

```
DB::table('shortcontacts')->where('mobile',($data->mobile))->update(['otp_stts'=>'Verified'])->orderBy('id','desc')->first();
```

Comment: I'm trying, it's updated all  row. I want only last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should sorting data to desc then updating like this:

```
DB::table('shortcontacts')->where('mobile',($data->mobile))->orderBy('id','desc')->first()->update(['otp_stts'=>'Verified']);
```

Comment: DB::table('shortcontacts')->where('mobile',($data->mobile))->update(['otp_stts'=>'Verified'])->orderBy('id','desc')->first();

Comment: you can't chained orderBy('id','desc') with update method because update return integer ,so do update then get data in other variable

Comment: I don't want get data. I need to update only last row inserted of a user.

Answer (score 1):

You can order your Model's data in descending order and select the first after that like this:

```
$lastUser = App\User::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

after you can update your model like this:

```
$lastUser->name = "New Name"; 
$lastUser->save();
```

UPDATE: you can also use the id field instead of 'created_at' for ordering your data.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
  $post = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
  $post->{column_name} = {value};
  $post->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest and oldest methods allow you to easily order results by date. By default, result will be ordered by the created_at column. Or, you may pass the column name that you wish to sort by:

```
$last = DB::table('shortcontacts')
                ->latest()
                ->first();
```